# Liste des meilleures ventes de livres en français

Tags: ressources, littérature

Pour améliorer mon français, je ne voudrais lire que les livres en français pour lesquels des traductions en anglais existent. Maintes fois, si je n'avais pas fait appel aux traductions anglaises, je ne me serais jamais rendu compte des phrases qui se sont avérées être l'argot, des idiomes, et des expressions fixées sur lesquelles j'étais bloqué.

Ainsi, je suis à la recherche d'une liste des meilleures ventes de livres en français. En particulier, je préfère les ouvrages non romanesques.

Y a-t-il des listes comme le « The New York Times Best Seller list » et les « Non-Fiction Charts » de la librairie brittannique WH Smith? J'ai trouvé les listes suivantes, mais il ne me semble pas qu'elles contiennent de « sous-listes » pour la littérature non romanesque :

- celle de la librairie française [ChaPitre](http://www.chapitre.com/CHAPITRE/fr/search/Default.aspx?n=4289587239&In_dim_search=1)
- celle de [Decitre](http://www.decitre.fr/livres/litterature/meilleures-ventes.html).

Comment: Intuitivement, je dirais [Le Petit Prince](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Petit_Prince) et [Astérix](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ast%C3%A9rix), mais ça reste romanesque. Je cite les meilleures ventes de livres français traduits dans d'autres langues.

Comment: Peut-être que des "livres bilingues" te conviendraient ? Mais c'est souvent des romans.

Answer (score 2):

Pour compléter les liens déjà mentionnés, le site [d'une librairie parisienne de renommée](http://livresnumeriques.gibertjeune.fr/SELECTIONS/GENERAL/0/77313-98026-98085.Selection) où les meilleures ventes sont présentées par références.